# How to pass the function and variables to remote server using SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, typeset

I have created myscript.sh file in one of local linux server. I am trying to pass the variables and functions defined in(myscript.sh) to remote machine.

```
my_var="Myvar Value"
getIPAddress()
        {       
                echo $my_var
                ip_address=$(hostname -i)
                echo $ip_address
        }   
ssh user@remote "$(typeset -f getIPAddress); getIPAddress"
```

I am only getting the ip_address but not getting the value of $my_var. Is there a way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass the value of the variable to the remote side. On the remote host, you re-create the function, but you don't create the variable the function depends on. You could do it with

```
ssh user@remote "$(typeset -f getIPAddress); my_var='$my_var'; getIPAddress"
```

or a bit shorter

```
ssh user@remote "$(typeset -f getIPAddress); my_var='$my_var' getIPAddress"
```

Note that in the first form, `my_var` is treated as shell variable, while in the second form, `my_var` is an environment variable inside your function.

I added quoting to catch the case that `my_var` contains white space.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
for server in foo bar base; do
    ssh user@$server <<-'EOF'
    my_var="Myvar Value"
    getIPAddress() {       
        echo "$my_var"
        ip_address="$(hostname -i)"
        echo "$ip_address"
    }
    getIPAddress
    EOF
done
```

Using shell *here-doc*.

See

```
man bash | less +/here-doc
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I need to run this for multiple remote servers and can't use EOF for each remote server as my shell script would be extremely long.

Comment: I not agree. See my edit